# Como melhorar a QUERY

Tags: php, mysql, query

Como eu poderia melhorar essa query, ela me retorna 30 registros de uma tabela que contém 43mil registros.

**NOTA**: Utilizo índice na coluna core (melhorou bastante).

```
((SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=5  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=6  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=4 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4));
```

Comment: já pensou em usar o `...where core in (3,2,5...) ... Limit 30`?

Comment: Sim, mas cada **core** tem o **limit** especifico.

Comment: Qual o tempo de execução dessa query ?

Comment: essa consulta que tu montou não era pra retornar apenas 30 resultados, porque retornou o total de 43k ?

Comment: Acho que primeiro é retirar esse random do order by

Comment: Falha minha! copy/paste, Resultado: **(30 total, 2,340 seg)**

Comment: Porque você ordena de forma aleatória ?

Comment: Felipe, precisa ser aleatório.

Comment: Preciso trazer registros aleatórios é obrigatório.

Comment: Entendo, mas randomizar o order by tira muita performance da query.

Comment: Exato!!! ainda está faltando mais uns 20mil registros para entrar...

Comment: Vou responder com a única coisa que consegue pensar para melhorar seu código, testa e ne fala se melhora o resultado.

Comment: O que pode ajudar é dividir essa consulta, em vez de uma, transforma em 6 e carrega elas de forma assíncrona, assim, o usuário vai lendo os primeiros enquanto carrega os demais. Não vai melhorar a performance, mas melhora a experiência do usuário

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Única coisa que consegui pensar para otimizar seu código é remover o `rand()` e colocar após o `union`, pois creio que ele é o que mais pesa. creio que executa-lo apenas uma vez é melhor do que executa-lo 6 vezes.

```
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=1 LIMIT 9)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=3 LIMIT 7)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=5 LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=6 LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=2 LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,situation,info FROM request WHERE core=4 LIMIT 4)
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Testa e me fala a diferença no resultado.

Comment: Minha primeira tentativa foi dessa forma, porém os resultados não vem na ordem tipo:
`core=1` + 9 registros
`core=2` + 7 registros etc...

Com o `ORDER BY RAND()` no final os registros vem fora de ordem

Comment: então no acaso você quer que o rand() seja "agrupado" por core? por exemplo: os valores de core 1 aleatórios depois os valores de core 3 aleatório e assim por diante ?

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso.

Comment: Então realmente você tem que fazer dessa forma que está fazendo. o que você pode fazer é usar esse artigo aqui e adequá-lo a seu caso. https://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/

Comment: Bom, vou da uma olhada nesse artigo, obrigado @Bulfaitelo.